# Defaulting to External Monitor when MacBook Pro Screen broken

Tags: macbook-pro, display

I have a MackBook Pro 15-inch (2016) with a broken screen. I can plug a standard USB-C to DisplayPort cable into it and it displays on my spare Dell monitor.

However to get this to work I have to power on the mac and quickly shut the lid so that it does not try and use the broken screen.

I have read that I can use the "Display" -> "Arrangements" menu to always default to external screen however I never see "Arrangements" in "Display". Is this because the Mac does not properly "see" the external display? If that is the case do I need to buy something like this [Apple USB-C Digital AV Multiport Adapter](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT207806)?

I want to get to the position where I never have to lift the lid of the Macbook. I am currently using a Logitech wireless Keyboard and Mouse set. I had hoped I could get them to wake the machine but that does not seem to work.

Comment: Unfortunately there is no way to turn on the MacBook with the lid closed (you can of course wake it from sleep with the external keyboard). I'm not sure what the first question is? It shouldn't matter when you close the lid, it will always switch to the external display as the main monitor if it is the only one present. Maybe you can describe the issue you're facing more clearly.

Comment: I rather naievely (or stupidly) thought i could wake if from off.

Comment: Well, it's not stupid. There used to be Macs that can be booted up over peripherals after all - The iMac G3 had a Power Button on the keyboard for example.